# Eigenvalues for T if and only if it is also eigenvalue of T inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ with $T \in \mathcal{L}(V, V)$ invertible and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F} \setminus \{0\}$. Prove that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $T$ if and only if $\lambda^{-1}$ (inverse) is an eigenvalue for $T^{-1}$ (inverse).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

$$Tv = \lambda v \iff v = T^{-1}\lambda v = \lambda T^{-1} v \iff T^{-1}v = \lambda^{-1}v$$

Comment: So you first multiply each side by T inverse?

Comment: @Larr I *apply* $T^{-1}$ on both sides.

Comment: I see, And then, if T -1 has an eigenvalue, so is T, right? Sorry don't know how to say T -1

Comment: @Larr [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  In particular, use `T^{-1}` for $T^{-1}$.  Yes, and they share the *same* eigenvector

Comment: Thanks! Math.SE similar to Latex?

Comment: @Larr Sorry I don't get your question.  The former is (supposed to be) a Q&A site for all levels of math, while the later is a technology for typesetting math.  I don't see how they are similar to each other.  Maybe you're asking for Math.SE vs TeX.SE: they are still different site on SE network.

Comment: lol I thought Math.SE is some kind of language in this site but thanks for clarifying that